# C++ WinAPI кастомный стиль для контрола

Tags: c++, winapi

Как например создать кнопку со своим стилем в WinAPI к примеру как ето делается в C# WPF? Или нужно рисовать rectangle, искать координаты и т.д самому?

Comment: В общем, да, рисовать вручную. Или возьмите какую-нибудь гуевую библиотеку, например, qt.

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет [Visual Styles API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/visual-styles-overview), в частности `SetWindowTheme`. Однако ковыряние с самими темами не на много проще рисования всего вручную, плюс оформление не такое гибкое.

Comment: меня интересует, верно ли рисовать таким образом.. контролы тоже рисуют так? вобщем не будет ли нарисованое мной например менее быстрое в отрисовке и т.д чем контрол

Comment: @MikeWaters Все стандартные контролы так отрисовываются.